Is it able to check XAML Designer mode in csproj?
I'm new to msbuild.
Is there a Condition key word to check if current environment is in the Visual Studio XAML Designer mode, not a actual WPF running environment? I would like to introduce some design resource library which only used for helping XAML designer work, but I don't want to include this library in the actual project.
How can I achieve the effect I want?
Expected:

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Condition=" '$(XamlDesignerMode)' == 'true' "
                      Include="..\DesignerResource\DesignerResource.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

Can someone share with me the steps to achieve this?

You might check if the private asset concept matches your needs, https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets but that condition doesn't exist.

Another possible approach is to test and see if the DesignTimeBuild property will work for your need.
